# MySQL sub query with variable

Tags: mysql, variables, subquery

How to pass a MySQL variable to a sub query something like as illustrated below.

```
select
 v.val, @var:= @var + 1 var 
from 
 (select val from table where id=@var) v, 
 (select @var:= 0) var
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
 v.val ,var
from 
(select val, @var:= @var + 1 var from Table1,(select @var:= 0) var where id=@var+1) v
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/765e9c/14

Comment: What if there are two tables say `table1` and `table2`? Means, something like `select
 v1.val1, v2.val2, @var:= @var + 1 var 
from 
 (select val1 from table1 where id=@var) v1,  (select val2 from table2 where id=@var) v2,
 (select @var:= 0) var`